# Beautifulsoup and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to using beautifulsoup therefore my question might seem like I am misunderstanding something, however here goes.

I am currently trying to make a synonym dictionary as the ones I can currently find are not amazing. In this regard I am building on someone elses work, the guy who made PyDictionary, therefore I am pulling synonyms from http://www.thesaurus.com/

In this example I am trying to pull only the noun synonyms from view-source:http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/animal?s=t

I have found this piece which indicates the the synonyms under the next relevancy block are nouns:

```
            <div class="synonym-description">
                <em class="txt">noun</em>
                <strong class="ttl">animate being; mammal</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="relevancy-block">
                <div class="relevancy-list">
```

My next question is essentially how do I specify that I only want to look in the class block "relevancy-list" directly after the class="txt>noun

After this I wanna look for the line

```
 <li><a href="http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pet" class="common-word" data-id="1" data-category="{&quot;name&quot;: &quot;relevant-3&quot;, &quot;color&quot;: &quot;#fcbb45&quot;}" data-complexity="1" data-length="1"><span class="text">pet</span><span class="star inactive">star</span></a></li>
```

And pull out the text under class="txt"

Currently I am loading it into an object via :

```
BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
```

How I am literally at a loss of where to go next, I have tried googling but to no real avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4
url = "http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/animal?s=t"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for txt in soup.find_all(class_="txt"):
    relevancy_list = txt.find_next(class_="relevancy-list")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped! I found the answer and will write it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the find_all function where the first argument is the type ('div', 'a' etc.) and in the second argument you can filter by class.

```
soup.find_all('em', {'class':"txt"})
```

This way you will get all 'em' with the class 'txt'.

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class':"relevancy-block"})
```

Here you will find all the 'div' with class name 'relevancy-block'

Comment: Awesome, then the next step would be, how do I look in the following div class="relevancy-block" after the first time I found noun?

Comment: @nonein , what do you mean found noun?

Comment: Sorry for not being super clear, I found the answer and will post it momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this thanks to both comments I received:

The following code first looks at the filters then subsequently if the filter is a noun or a verb, if it is a noun it lists all the nouns classified as common-words

```
def _get_soup_object(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

term="animal" 

data = _get_soup_object("http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/{0}".format(term))

for selector_var in data.find_all(class_="filters"):

    word_type=selector_var.find_all(class_="txt")
    if word_type[0].text=="adj":
        print("This is an adjective, which we don't want")

    elif word_type[0].text=="noun":
        print("This is a noun, which we do want")

        word_list=selector_var.find_all(class_="common-word")
        for indv_word in word_list:
            print(indv_word.text[:-4])
```